# RestClient for Elastic Search

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to fetch data from Elastic search cluster. 
Index Name  : testIndex
Type : testType
host : localhost
port : 8080

I want to use Elastic Search 5.4 version and using RestClient I would like to fetch data using multimatch query.

Sample Query would look something like this.

```
GET testIndex/testType/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query":"slabs",
      "fields": ["field1","field2"]
    }
  }
}
```

What would be the best way to do that ?  Is it possible that I can use QueryBuilder to build queries and use that with rest client.

Answer (score 0):

The QueryBuilder for the RestClient will be available when version 6 is released. There will be a Low Level and a High Level REST Client. The High Level REST client will support the QueryBuilder. You can already play around with it here:

[QueryBuilder with High Level REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.0/java-rest-high-query-builders.html)

Until then, the QueryBuilder is not available for the REST Client so with version 5.4 you need to build the queries yourself. There a many ways to do this.

One way is to use a language template like [jTwig](http://jtwig.org/). A very nice example on how to do this is explained by Jettro Coenradie [here](https://amsterdam.luminis.eu/2016/07/25/the-new-elasticsearch-java-rest-client-part-2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
RestClient client = new RestClient(serverhost, port,username, password);
SearchSourceBuilder query = new SearchSourceBuilder();
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(IndexName);
searchRequest.source(query);
SearchResponse searchResponse = restClient.search(IndexName , query);
```

You should use Rest client for creating connection with elasticsearch andfor query request and search response you should use SearchSourceBuilder , SearchRespons. and for query you can use QueryBuilders of elastic search.